# Number of days, weeks,months,years,quarters since 2000

Tags: sql, datetime, oracle11g

I need to populate a calendar table in a Oracle 11g database with the following:
calendar_date,
week_number,
week_year,
day_since_2000,
week_since_2000,
month_since_2000,
quarter_since_2000,
week_of_month

The table is already populated with data since 2000 I now need to populate it going back to 1994 with negative numbers for the since_2000 columns. I think I have everything figured but for week since 2000 and quarter since 2000.

EDIT1: Just noticed my week since 200 and month since 2000 is still messed up. Quarter since 2000 looks good after using the answer mentioned below. I am updating the query with the latest.

EDIT2: It was not working because of the missing trunc(). Its working fine now. Latest query updated.

This is what I am using to do that:

```
/* Formatted on 2/1/2013 11:54:27 AM (QP5 v5.227.12220.39724) */
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE populate_d_calendar (start_date     IN DATE,
                         end_date       IN DATE)
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO d_calendar (calendar_date,
               week_number,
               week_year,
               day_since_2000,
               week_since_2000,
               month_since_2000,
               quarter_since_2000,
               week_of_month)
      SELECT dt,                                                        --Date
         TO_CHAR (dt,
              'ww'),                                --Week in the year
         TO_CHAR (dt,
              'yyyy'),                                          --Year
         TO_CHAR (dt - end_date),                         --Day Since 2000
         TRUNC (TO_CHAR (dt - end_date) / 7),            --Week Since 2000
         TRUNC (MONTHS_BETWEEN (dt,
                    end_date)),             --Month Since 2000
         CASE
        WHEN TO_CHAR (dt,
                  'MMDD') >= '0101'
         AND TO_CHAR (dt,
                  'MMDD') < '0401'
        THEN
             0
           +   4
             * TRUNC (  MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (   '0101'
                             || TO_CHAR (dt,
                                     'yyyy'),
                             'mmddyyyy'),
                        TO_DATE ('01Jun2000'))
                  / 12)                                       --q1
        WHEN TO_CHAR (dt,
                  'MMDD') >= '0401'
         AND TO_CHAR (dt,
                  'MMDD') < '0701'
        THEN
             1
           +   4
             * TRUNC (  MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (   '0101'
                             || TO_CHAR (dt,
                                     'yyyy'),
                             'mmddyyyy'),
                        TO_DATE ('01Jun2000'))
                  / 12)                                       --q2
        WHEN TO_CHAR (dt,
                  'MMDD') >= '0701'
         AND TO_CHAR (dt,
                  'MMDD') < '1001'
        THEN
             2
           +   4
             * TRUNC (  MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (   '0101'
                             || TO_CHAR (dt,
                                     'yyyy'),
                             'mmddyyyy'),
                        TO_DATE ('01Jun2000'))
                  / 12)                                       --q3
        WHEN TO_CHAR (dt,
                  'MMDD') >= '1001'
         AND TO_CHAR (dt,
                  'MMDD') <= '1231'
        THEN
             3
           +   4
             * TRUNC (  MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE (   '0101'
                             || TO_CHAR (dt,
                                     'yyyy'),
                             'mmddyyyy'),
                        TO_DATE ('01Jun2000'))
                  / 12)                                       --q4
         END
        quarters_since_2000,                      --Quarter Since 2000
         TO_CHAR (dt,
              'w')                                 --Week of the month
    FROM (SELECT start_date + LEVEL - 1 dt
        FROM DUAL
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= end_date - start_date + 1);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you're after a floating point like with the others so maybe:

```
TO_CHAR (dt - end_date)/7 week_since_2000
```

and

```
(MONTHS_BETWEEN (dt,
            end_date)/3) quarter_since_2000
```

Comment: Its not working right. Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3df6c/1). Let me know if I have messed something up.

Answer (score 1):

with **weeks** you can follow one of the methods here:

http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/Calculating-weeks-between-two-dates

because it will depend on which rules are more useful to you

with **quarters**, use this:

```
case 
         WHEN TO_CHAR (dt,'MMDD') >= '0101' and TO_CHAR (dt,'MMDD') < '0401' then  0 + 4 * trunc(months_between( to_date('0101' || to_char(dt,'yyyy'),'mmddyyyy'),to_date('01Jun2000' )) /12)   --q1
         WHEN TO_CHAR (dt,'MMDD') >= '0401' and TO_CHAR (dt,'MMDD') < '0701' then  1 + 4 * trunc(months_between( to_date('0101' || to_char(dt,'yyyy'),'mmddyyyy'),to_date('01Jun2000' )) /12)  --q2
         WHEN TO_CHAR (dt,'MMDD') >= '0701' and TO_CHAR (dt,'MMDD') < '1001' then  2 + 4 * trunc(months_between( to_date('0101' || to_char(dt,'yyyy'),'mmddyyyy'),to_date('01Jun2000' )) /12)  --q3
         WHEN TO_CHAR (dt,'MMDD') >= '1001' and TO_CHAR (dt,'MMDD') <= '1231' then 3 + 4 * trunc(months_between( to_date('0101' || to_char(dt,'yyyy'),'mmddyyyy'),to_date('01Jun2000' )) /12)   --q4
         end         quarters_since_2000,
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my version of calendar table from 1/1/2013 till today. I'm not sure how do you need to insert number of months, quarters, days etc... You need to display total number of months between every year or once? You can add those calc yourself or add desired output in your post to make it clear. See addl queries/comments below:

```
-- Days,weeks, quarters from 1/1/2013 --
SELECT start_date                               -- 1/1/2013 --
    , TRUNC(start_date, 'iw')                  wk_starts  
    , TRUNC(start_date, 'iw') + 7 - 1/86400    wk_ends
    , TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (start_date, 'IW'))   ISO_wk#  
    , TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (start_date, 'Q'))    Quarters  
 FROM
  (
   SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Y')-1 + LEVEL AS start_date  
     FROM dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 
  (  -- replace this part to go back to 1994 - see below --
  SELECT TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, 12), 'Y')-TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Y') "Num of Days in 2013"   
    FROM dual
  )
)
/

START_DATE  WK_STARTS   WK_ENDS                 ISO_WK#     QUARTERS
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1/1/2013    12/31/2012  1/6/2013 11:59:59 PM    1           1
1/2/2013    12/31/2012  1/6/2013 11:59:59 PM    1           1
......
2/19/2013   2/18/2013   2/24/2013 11:59:59 PM   8           1
2/20/2013   2/18/2013   2/24/2013 11:59:59 PM   8           1
......
3/10/2013   3/4/2013    3/10/2013 11:59:59 PM   10          1
3/11/2013   3/11/2013   3/17/2013 11:59:59 PM   11          1
.......

-- 6971 days from 1/1/1994 till today - 2/1/2013 --
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -12*19), 'Y') "Num of Days from 1994"
  FROM dual
/

-- 4780 days from 1/1/2000 till today - 2/1/2013 --
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -12*13), 'Y') "Num of Days from 2000"
  FROM dual
/

-- 156 Months between from 2000 toll today --
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE), TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -12*13))) mo_btw_2000_till_today 
  FROM dual
/

-- Number of weeks btw. 2 dates -- 
SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'WW') - to_char(sysdate-30, 'WW') number_of_weeks FROM dual
/
```

This may not be exactly what you want... To help you more I need to see the actual expected output of your query. Just trying to help...

Comment: Thanks !!! I have what I want and have updated the post with the query that worked for me. The answers above from baranov and DazzaL helped me get what I want.

Comment: @Swapna Mohan - Thank you for the fiddle. Some reading about weeks per mo: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date